# MSSQL count number of items based on time differences

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table (tbl_results) of information like so:

```
name  | time_in_minutes
-------------
jonny | 14
jonny | 27
jonny | 28
jonny | 56
jonny | 57
jonny | 58
sarah | 12
sarah | 16
sarah | 17
sarah | 24
sarah | 25
```

and i would love to know how to write a query (cross join maybe?), that sums up the number of times within a certain time period. For the example above I would use timings of 10 minutes. So the following would be the result.

```
name  | 0-10 | 11-20 | 21-30 | 31-40 | 41-50 | 51-60
jonny |   0  |   1   |   2   |   0   |   0   |   3
sarah |   0  |   3   |   2   |   0   |   0   |   0
```

I would write some code, but I am really not even sure where to start with a query like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    name,
    [0-10]  = COUNT(CASE WHEN time_in_minutes BETWEEN 0 AND 10 THEN 1 END),
    [11-20] = COUNT(CASE WHEN time_in_minutes BETWEEN 0 AND 10 THEN 1 END),
    [21-30] = COUNT(CASE WHEN time_in_minutes BETWEEN 0 AND 10 THEN 1 END),
    [31-40] = COUNT(CASE WHEN time_in_minutes BETWEEN 0 AND 10 THEN 1 END),
    [41-50] = COUNT(CASE WHEN time_in_minutes BETWEEN 0 AND 10 THEN 1 END),
    [51-60] = COUNT(CASE WHEN time_in_minutes BETWEEN 0 AND 10 THEN 1 END)
FROM tbl
GROUP BY name
```

Comment: fantastic! Thats perfect.

I updated it to the below as it needed a little adjusting;

    SELECT name, 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN time_in_minutes BETWEEN 0 AND 10 THEN 1 END) as [0-10],
    COUNT(CASE WHEN time_in_minutes BETWEEN 11 AND 20 THEN 1 END) as [11-20],
    COUNT(CASE WHEN time_in_minutes BETWEEN 21 AND 30 THEN 1 END) as [21-30],
    COUNT(CASE WHEN time_in_minutes BETWEEN 31 AND 40 THEN 1 END) as [31-40],
    COUNT(CASE WHEN time_in_minutes BETWEEN 41 AND 50 THEN 1 END) as [41-50],
    COUNT(CASE WHEN time_in_minutes BETWEEN 51 AND 60 THEN 1 END) as [51-60]
FROM...